# How to use call wrappers for Intent Anko?

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, anko

I am learning `Anko` commons and in that, I see `Intent` for easy to write code to startActivity. It's working. But in that I see Anko has call wrappers for some widely used Intents:

```
Goal                 Solution
------------         -------------------
Make a call          makeCall(number) without tel:
Send a text          sendSMS(number, [text]) without sms:
Browse the web       browse(url)
Share some text      share(text, [subject])
Send a email         email(email, [subject], [text])
```

So I want to use this wrapper but don't know how. How can I use this?

Reference Like:  https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Commons-%E2%80%93-Intents#useful-intent-callers

**@9spl** what you have written in the answer I know that all and I have used the latest dependency but my first question was how to use **makeCall()**. But I got that answer how to use then I have another problem, **makeCall()** doesn't work. I have declared permission in manifest although it's not working. why?

**sendSMS()** and **browse()** both are working but **makeCall()** is not working.

Comment: Include Anko (`compile "org.jetbrains...."`) and call one of these functions from `Activity` (while not in Activity, you can specify it explicitly, e. g. `activity.browse(...)`).

Comment: yes, it's working. Thanks. But one more problem when I use `makeCall()` it doesn't work. why?

Comment: What happens when you call `makeCall()`? Are there any logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just make sure you have added right dependency for anko in your app gradle

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.1.2-3"

compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.0"
```

Now it is so easy to use it use this as a functions of Anko
Ex.if you want to make call just simply call this function like

`makeCall("PHONE_NUMBER")`

Comment: All is working well but my next problem is when I call `makeCall()` it doesn't work

Comment: Make sure you have given call permission in Manifest  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/> and same for others..@PatelPinkal

Comment: I don't think you need specifically `kotlin-stdlib-jre7`. From what I know `kotlin-stdlib` should work too.

Comment: hi @PatelPinkal are you testing on Emulator or real device , Does real device have Sim Card in it?

Comment: I have tried in both emulator and device with Sim card but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CALL_PHONE permission i.e `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>` in the Manifest file and also ask the user for run-time CALL_PHONE permission.